# Saving plotly figure in Linux causes GL_INVALID_OPERATION

Tags: python-3.x, linux-mint, plotly-python

I am running a simple script to save a plotly figure as a PNG file inside a Python 3.7.5 venv on Linux Mint 19.1. There is a local version of orca-1.3.1.AppImage inside the venv, as there is a global package called orca v. 3.28.0 which is being used by a long list of processes. I believe this global orca is a different package entirely as plotly does not accept it as valid.

This MWE runs, shows the figure and creates a PNG file of it, but also shows an error message.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.7

import plotly

plotly.io.orca.config.executable = '/path/to/venv/bin/orca-1.3.1.AppImage'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    fig = plotly.graph_objects.Figure()
    fig.show()                           # <-This line does not cause an error
    fig.write_image("test_plot.png")     # <-This is the problem
```

Error:

```
[29435:0922/095617.801602:ERROR:buffer_manager.cc(488)] [.DisplayCompositor]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glBufferData: <- error from previous GL command
```

Any suggestions for why this is, if it is important, and how I can remedy it?

Comment: I'm getting the same using orca in RStudio.

Comment: Orca is notoriously glitchy and breaks easily.  You might have luck using the --disable-gpu flag (not sure how to implement this in orca for python).  See https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/7834#issuecomment-275802528 for how to use this.